# Async parameters for URL

Tags: android, json, android-virtual-device

To make long story short.
This is the tutorial that I am following,
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

I ran this on local host on mysql and it is working fine on the AVD.

Now after analyzing the code and everything I have created a mysql database with all the same structure as the tutorial, but of course on the web on my hostgator account.

Then when I try to run the app and try to register an account, my app keeps crashing and I get the

android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

So I understand that I need to have ASYNC so that this task can be done in the background and not on the main UI thread. But my question is why was it able to work on the localhost just fine?

Now to my actual problem, where and what are the parameters for the ASYNC i have to provide? I am thinking I should have at a common place, if you refer to the tutorial above, there is in JSON parser class?
So below is UserFunction Class if you have seen the tutorial above this is one of the class, but the difference is I am trying to make the login task to ASYNTASK and having difficulty in understanding , ASYNC task, yes I have seen the google document but still can't figure out what arguments to put for my case. Help appreciated tks, its easy for me to understand from a completed code by putting in breakpoints and logging to understand the internals.

```
My UserFunctions Class

package databasehandler;

/**
 * Created by YP on 26-Nov-14.
 */

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.techiequickie.bharath.boadraf.Loginactivity;
import com.techiequickie.bharath.boadraf.choose_task;

public class UserFunctions
{
    private JSONParser jsonParser;

    public static String loginURL = "http://techiequickie.com/android_login_api/";
    private static String registerURL = "http://techiequickie.com/android_login_api/";

    private static String login_tag = "login";
    private static String register_tag = "register";

    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }


    private class myAsynTask extends AsyncTask <URL, Void, String >
    {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(URL... params)
        {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            if(result.equals("1"))
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(UserFunctions.this,choose_task.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * 
    public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
        // return json
        // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param name
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password,String preffered_username){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("preffered", preffered_username));


        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * Function get Login status
     * */
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        int count = db.getRowCount();
        if(count > 0){
            // user logged in
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Function to logout user
     * Reset Database
     * */
    public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db.resetTables();
        return true;
    }



}
```

Comment: No not `ASYNC` but `AsyncTask`. The json parser class does also the download from url. This is quite confusing. You could better use an AsyncTask to download the json text (String json in JSONObject getJSONFromUrl) in doInBackgrount. And the in onPostExecute convert it to a json object with `jObj = new JSONObject(json);`. And then continue from that onPostExecute. So you need a little redesign.

Comment: Your AsyncTask should have about the same parameters as `JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params)`. So give it a constructor so you can use `new MyAsyncTask(params).execute(url);`.

Comment: The reason you were able to run this on AVD, you was testing it on an older AVD.

Comment: @greenapps can you please show that in the code? I think I understand what you are trying to say and it might just work, but unsure where exactly I have to place ( I mean in which class)

Comment: Please show complete code of the AsyncTask class that you have now. Then we will try to adapt.

Comment: At the moment i have none, that is the whole confusion for me. Where should I even include one? in JSON parser class? Kindly do refer to the tutorial i posted in my question so as to understand what I mean. I am having the same classes as the tutorial. Thankyou very much

Comment: Define your MyAsyncTask class in the UserFunctions claas as you are going to use it there as you will know as you will change (as already was said) `JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params);` to someting like `MyAsyncTask(params).execute(url);`.

Comment: @greenapps I have added my UserFunctions class, but still unsure on the params for MyAsyncTask. Tks

Comment: Keep the loginUser function. Only change one line for another (i already twice told you which lines). Remove the `return json;`. Add a constructor for your asynctask. In onPostExecute call the function which you otherwise would call after succesfull login. Adapt the code here.

Comment: sorry, i am new to networking, mainly from UX/UI background.. trying my best.

Answer (score 0):

This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged. So if your AVD is running under SDK lower then Honeycomb NetworkOnMainThreadException will not be thrown.

You should do network stuff on background thread. You can use many tools to reach that goal, to name but a few: AsyncTask, ThreadPoolExecutor, simple new Thread, etc.

Comment: tks for clearing that. But what are the params. and in which class should I decalare that? if choose to go with AsyncTask

Comment: `AsyncTask` has a good documentation [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You can find example of simple usage there.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not allow network operations on the main thread. This is because a network operation on the main thread will lock up the UI.

For most of my network calls on android, I use a helper called [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which is built into Android.

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI
>   thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask) is a good tutorial for learning how to implement an AsyncTask